# Create mailbox alias in Arabic

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server

I have a requirement to create the mailboxes of the users with their mailbox alias in Arabic.

I want to know that does Microsoft Exchange allows non-English characters for the alias attribute?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Arabic not allowed..

> The value of Alias can contain letters, numbers and the characters !,
>   '#', $, %, &, ', *, +, -, /, =, ?, ^, _, `, {, |, } and ~. Periods (.) are allowed, but each period must be surrounded by other valid
>   characters (for example, help.desk). Unicode characters from U+00A1 to
>   U+00FF are also allowed. The maximum length of the Alias value is 64
>   characters.
>
> When you create a recipient without specifying an email address, the
>   Alias value you specify is used to generate the primary email address
>   (@). Supported Unicode characters are mapped to
>   best-fit US-ASCII text characters. For example, U+00F6 (ö) is changed
>   to oe in the primary email address.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/enable-mailuser?view=exchange-ps